# Discussing the continuity and differentiability of $f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{e^x}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Check Continuity and differentiability of the given function. Also tell the limit of function at infinity.
$$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{\frac{1}{e^x}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1} & \quad  \text{if} \space x \not= 0 \\
            1 & \quad \text{if}\space x = 0.
        \end{array}
    \right.
 $$

---

I have been trying to rearrange the given function in arrangements that ease the calculations but haven't succeeded so far and after a lot of frustration, I'm posting it here.

Here's what I tried:

We obviously would have to show that the Left Hand Limit(LHL) and Right Hand Limit(RHL) of $f(x)$ when $x \not=0$ is equal to 1 for it to be continuous.

So, LHL:

$$L=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{e^{-h}}-1}{e^{\frac{-1}{h}}+1}$$
$$L=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} f(x)=\frac{\left(e^h-1\right).e^{\frac{1}{h}}}{e^{\frac{1}{h}}+1}$$

Multiplying denominator and numerator with h,

$$L=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} f(x)=\frac{h.e^{\frac{1}{h}}}{e^{\frac{1}{h}}+1}$$

I get stuck to a similar situation while calculating RHL.

I can't get to a form where I can use some other identity or get $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form which would enable me to use Lhopital's rule.

For reference, the answer given to the problem says that the function is:

> Right Continuous at $x=0$ and limit at infinity is $0$

Comment: There are issues at $x=0$ to check, but otherwise you have addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and exponentiation of continuous differentiable functions ($e>0$ and $e^{1/x}+1 >0$), so elsewhere the whole function is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: I suspect you may actually want $f(0)=0$ rather than $1$ for continuity

Comment: @Henry Yes. I am sorry that I didn't mention it. The answer given says it's 'Right continuous' at x=0 so I guess that explains it. I can't get how you concluded that it's continuous and differentiable. Could you please elaborate with a few steps?

Comment: Away from $x=0$ the derivative is $\frac{{{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}}\cdot \left( {{e}^{-x}}-1\right) }{{{x}^{2}}\cdot {{\left( {{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}}+1\right) }^{2}}}-\frac{{{e}^{-x}}}{{{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}}+1}$ which works happily.

Comment: The function isn't continuous at $x=0$. Neither right or left limit exist at $x=0$. Isn't it? Also limit at infinity is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @YathirajSharma Yes, limit at infinity seems to be -1/2 according to the graph. But the limit does exist at the right so it is right continuous. Have a look at the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gbx4wrh4mh

Comment: Sorry I mean limit exists at 0 but not equal to 1. Both LHL and RHL are 0. I wanted to say that. Please make that correction.